# How to Set the Source Parameter using OAuth on Twitter?

Tags: javascript, firefox, twitter, oauth

my name is Fernando and I was here asking if there was a way to set the parameter 'source' using REST. Today, after some testing, I managed to implement OAuth in the library and I succeeded in publishing a message directly by OAuth configured for my application, but do not see what I had set for the field source, even using OAuth and working in this part . Now, as I do for the Source parameter is set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use OAuth Twitter automatically adds the source parameter for you using the information from the application registration form.